# Can I have dynamic "touchRegionId" in MotionLayout?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-motionlayout

For now, I use a view from the first screen as touchRegionId. The problem is that the view is only at the first screen and when "start->end" animation is done, I'm unable to make "end->start" animation, because I don't have that view from touchRegionId. If it's not possible to have dynamic "touchRegionId", what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an Invisible View as a TouchRegionID and Constrain it to where ever you want it to be in each screen.